# Analog of MEAN.JS stack for Hapi.js

Tags: mean-stack, hapi.js

MEAN.JS is a full-stack JavaScript solution that helps you build fast, robust, and maintainable production web applications using MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, and Node.js.

In this formula I want to replace Express by Hapi.js.

Does anybody know analog of MEAN.JS but for Hapi.js?

Comment: There are some hapi boilerplates here: http://hapijs.com/resources

Comment: @MattHarrison Of course I checked hapijs.com/resources first. There is hanx.js but it uses PostgreSQL instead of MongoDB and also it's a bit outdated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell [hanx.js](https://github.com/youhusam/hanx.js) is the closest match to MEAN.js. The downside is as you already mentioned that it uses PostgreSQL and you are looking for MongoDB.

There is also [frame](https://github.com/jedireza/frame) but it brings only the server side to the table. You need to build your own client.

Hope this helps you a bit.